# Http request failure using httpClient module in a ionic 3 application

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, http-headers, ionic3

I got the following error

`Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`

while I sent a http request on real device (Android) using Ionic 3 framework.

> On browser the http request was successfully done.

After research, I concluded that the issue is related to CORS failure as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22022).

What I tried to do is enable the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the header request

```
  private addToken(request: HttpRequest < any > , token: any) {
    let clone: HttpRequest < any > ;
    if (token) {
      clone = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Accept: `application/json`,
          'Content-Type': `application/json`,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    } else {
      clone = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Accept: `application/json`,
          'Content-Type': `application/json`,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*", // -------------- > HERE
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
        }
      });
      console.log(clone);
    }
    return clone;
  };
```

> Please note: The code above is used for http interceptor.

And same error.

It's really related to CORS issue? and what is the solution? or it is back-end issue?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#requesting-services-from-a-different-server-cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was server side issue (ASP.net), CORS should be allowed. I assumed that the issue it was from the front-end side.

Thanks.